# Why is necessary to explicitly say a lambda is Consumer to use andThen method?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I've faced a strange(for me) behavior when I was trying to use function composition with two void methods. I've written a simple example to illustrate the problem :

```
public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();

        // 1) Does not compile
        foos.forEach(Startup::doSomething1.andThen(Startup::doSomething2));

        Consumer<Foo> doSomething1 = Startup::doSomething1;
        Consumer<Foo> doSomething2 = Startup::doSomething2;

        // 2) Works as expected 
        foos.forEach(doSomething1.andThen(doSomething2));

    }

    public static void doSomething1(Foo foo) {

    }

    public static void doSomething2(Foo foo) {

    }

    public static class Foo {

    }

}
```

When I try to compile the first solution it says "')' expected" before andThen call.

When I explicitly say this are Consumers the code is compiled and it works as expected.

Can anyone explain to my why this is happening and is there another way of doing function composition of void methods with Java 8?

Comment: Expecting `Startup::doSomething1` to be strictly a `Consumer<Foo>`? No, it can also be a `interface FooTaker{void takeFoo(Foo f);}`... But before that, this is a question of syntax...

Comment: My guess is that the implicit conversion from method handle to `Consumer<Foo>` hasn't happened at the point you use the `.` token; an explicit cast might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the way Java inferes, converts and detects types in lambdas. As mentioned in a comment above, the conversion to `Consumer<Foo>` has not taken place yet meaning that the compiler does not know that this is a `Consumer` so that you can chain an `andThen()` afterwards.

Explicitly casting this to a `Consumer` and using parentheses properly will let you achieve the desired effect:

```
List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
foos.forEach(((Consumer<Foo>) Null::doSomething).andThen(Null::doSomething2));
```

I guess if you fiddle around with it, you can achieve the same behavior using type witnesses but I am not 100% sure whether they can achieve the desired result.

First time I noticed this was using chained comparators which may exhibit the same behavior. Doing an online search about that will show you some more intricate details regarding how this works.

Answer (score 5):

Let's make this simpler:

```
 private static boolean test(String input){
       return input.equals("123");
 }

 Predicate<String> predicate = YourClass::test;
 Function<String, Boolean> function = YourClass::test;
```

So a method reference is a *poly* expression (like generics for example), they depend on the context where they are used. So your `Startup::doSomething` method reference could be *any* `@FunctionalInterface` that would comply to the that method. It might look to you that it is a `Consumer` in this case, but it's a different story for the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) mentioned:

> This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the **assignment target** for a lambda expression or method reference.

And the *functional interface* gives us two methods:

1. `void accept(T t)`
2. `default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after)`

As for `andThen(...)`:

> Returns a **composed Consumer** that performs, in sequence, this operation followed by the after operation.

The **Functional Interface** is the syntactic sugar that Java 8 provides that we can just pass in a `lambda` or `method reference`, and we can get more helpful/assistant features that we frequently need (default behaviors).

And here, we can combine several functions altogether easily using `andThen`

As for your case, you can just try something like this:

```
public class CastToFunctionalInterface {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ((Consumer<Integer>) CastToFunctionalInterface::consumeInteger)
                .andThen(CastToFunctionalInterface::consumeAnotherInteger)
                .accept(10);
    }

    private static void consumeInteger(Integer a) {
        System.out.println("I'm an Integer: " + a);
    }

    private static void consumeAnotherInteger(Integer b) {
        System.out.println("I'm another integer: " + b);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I'm an Integer: 10
I'm another integer: 10
```